# Add input fields and validate the sum against total using javascript

Tags: javascript, c#, webmatrix

I am trying to get the sum of the values entered into the age input fields upon change.  Then I need to validate the sum of ages against the total number of students trained.  If the total number of students trained does not match the sum of the students ages I want to throw an error. I am coding in C#.

Here is my html code:

```
<h4>Training</h4>
<b>Total number of students in training:</b> <input type="number" name="Total Number students trained" min="0"><span style="color: #f00">
<h5>Ages of Students </h5>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td><label for="age 18" class="float-left"> &#060;18:</label> <input type="number" min="0" max="500" name="age 18" oninput="calcage"> </td>
            <td><label for="age 24" class="float-left">18-24:</label> <input type="number" min="0" name="age 24 oninput="calcage"> </td>
            <td><label for="age 34" class="float-left">25-34:</label> <input type="number"min="0" name="age 34" oninput="calcage"> </td>
            <td><label for="age 44" class="float-left">35-44:</label> <input type="number" min="0" name="age 44" oninput="calcage"> </td>
        </tr>
</table>
```

Here is my javascript:

```
function calcage() {
    var score = 0;
    $(".age:input").each(function () {
        score += parseInt(this.value);
    });
    $("input[name=Score]").val(score)
}

$().ready(function () {
    $(".age").change(function () {
        calcage()
    });
});
```

Comment: You have to show us what you've attempted as far as functionality. StackOverflow isn't a coding service. You didn't so much as specify a language.

Comment: Yeah, it's not clear from what you've shown where you are stuck. Can you show the code? Also, is this javascript or c#

Comment: The inputs don't have a `class="age"` which is what your selector is looking for

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your HTML has a few errors:

1. Your `<input>` elements need to have `class="age"` added to them so that they are recognized by the `$(".age:input").each()` function.
2. The `name` of your second `<input>` element is missing the closing double quote (`"`).
3. You are missing the parentheses (`()`) after the `calcage` calls in your `oninput` events. However, since you are using the `$(".age").change()` function to call the `calcage()` function, it is not necessary to also have the `oninput` event call the `calcage()` function. Also, the `oninput` event is called every time an input changes without waiting until all changes are complete. This means that if a student entered an age of "30", the `calcage` function would be called twice: first for the "3", and then again for the "0". Since this is not what you want, those event handlers can be removed from the inputs. Leave `$(".age").change()` since this will only fire once the student has finished typing. It will work once your `<input>` elements have the `class="age"` added to them.
4. The `<label>` elements for attribute will only work when there is an `<input>` element with a matching `id` value.

Try the following corrected HTML:

```
<h4>Training</h4>
<b>Total number of students in training:</b> <input type="number" name="Total Number students trained" min="0"><span style="color: #f00">
<h5>Ages of Students </h5>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td><label for="age 18" class="float-left"> &#060;18:</label> <input class="age" type="number" min="0" max="500" name="age 18"> </td>
            <td><label for="age 24" class="float-left">18-24:</label> <input class="age" type="number" min="0" name="age 24"> </td>
            <td><label for="age 34" class="float-left">25-34:</label> <input class="age" type="number" min="0" name="age 34"> </td>
            <td><label for="age 44" class="float-left">35-44:</label> <input class="age" type="number" min="0" name="age 44"> </td>
        </tr>
</table>
```